# How to organize a microservice architecture with Ocelot and RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, microservices, ocelot

I'm currently designing a microservice architecture for work.  For now, I'm having my initial application issue POST requests to an Ocelot API Gateway.  This API Gateway should forward the requests to a RabbitMQ exchange, which then transfers them to a consumer queue.  It's from this queue that I will issue requests between my queue and various microservices.

In fewer words: Main -> API Gateway -> Message Exchange -> Message Queue -> Microservices

My question is this: how do I produce a message to the exchange from the Ocelot API Gateway?  From what I understand, this is more for rewriting/rerouting requests.  I've tried finding instances of handling RabbitMQ via middleware, but nothing from my few findings quite matched what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a problem where Ocelot does not help to much. REST APIs tend to spread data to a certain degree (in the route and/or body) and MessageQueue have all in the message. So the mayor problem to solve is mapping the differing model. Finding the right Queue for the RestAPI seems like a minor problem (easy to solve by hand without a 3rd party) to me where something like Ocelot does not help as most things like forwarding headers, enriching headers do not have a direct representation in a MessageQueue so are useless features here.